# Parsing HTML file for a particular value

Tags: c#, regex, html-parsing

I have a number of HTML files and I want to extract a particular value from all those files.

```
<div class="ABC">Value</div>
```

I want to extract the `Value` from all the pages. Should I use regex or some HTML parsing libraries?
I am not very much familiar with regex, and I couldn't find any documentation of HTML library - HTML Agility.

Which approach should I follow? If I should use Regex, Or library or is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: [Relevant - Parsing HTML With Regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: @tnw Relevant to **this** question: the answer below that.

Answer (score -1):

The most recommended way is to parse it by Your own.

You will need to create a method, but in the future You will have it as Your own tool, evolving whith every problem.

Take a look :

[How to get IMG tag's source from given HTML string using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16664532/how-to-get-img-tags-source-from-given-html-string-using-c-sharp/16664624#16664624)

Comment: This is essentially exactly what you _don't_ want to do.

Comment: Why ?
Can You explain, Thomas ? You posted, what i linked to .
Ao where is the difference ?

Comment: Roll your own XML parser for this one task is absurd, and is in most general cases for anything.

Comment: A ) He is talking about HTML.
B ) all Your keywords are the same stuff, which i linked too.

Comment: HTML _is_ XML (albeit its ugly child), the keywords I linked would allow you to parse someone _very specific_ as an irony to this instance and not something to just use on a whim for this kind of task.